# Unable to initialise Swiper in angular2 using npm

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, swiper.js

I am trying to use the swiper library in my angular2 + npm application but am having an error on build when trying to use it

The error is:

```
ERROR in vendor.95f9dda80938ded736ad.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (class_SwiperClass) [vendor.95f9dda80938ded736ad.bundle.js:16626,6]
```

I have included it in my package.json and am using it as follows in my component:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper/src/components/core/core-class';


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let mySwiper : any = new Swiper('swiper-container', {
      autoplay: 1000,
      autoplayDisableOnInteraction : false,
      speed: 400,
      spaceBetween: 0,
      pagination : ".swiper-pagination"
    });
  }
```

My angular-cli configuration is as follows:

```
 {
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/swiper/dist/css/swiper.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Swiper in my app in this way:

1. You must install swiper with npm --> npm install swiper@3.4.2 --save
2. You must add in your agular-cli.json:
   "styles": ["../node_modules/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" ],
   "scripts": ["../node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"]
3. You must add in your typings.d.ts --> declare var Swiper: any;
4. Now in your component.ts remove import Swiper and your slider works! let me known!

Comment: what you mean with You must add in your typings.d.ts --> declare var Swiper: any; i dont have any typings.d.ts

Comment: When you use Javascript library you must download typings for your library (in this case Swiper). If the global library you need to use does not have global typings, you can also declare them manually in src/typings.d.ts as any: declare var libraryName: any; (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)